# SvelteKit: how can I add global error 401 handling?

Tags: sveltekit

How can you globally handle 401 errors that come from **an external** API?

First of all, my setup:

1. When the user logs in I set a `jwt` cookie, write a `jwt` property to the `session` store (from `$app/stores`), and redirect to the protected portion of the website.
2. In `hooks.js` I have a `handle` function that basically does `request.locals.jwt = cookies.jwt`, and then a `getSession` function that returns `{ jwt: locals.jwt }`
3. On every `fetch` request that I make on the protected pages, I access and use `session.jwt` to send the token to the API.

That whole setup works. If the user logs out, I can just write an empty JWT cookie and clear the `$session.jwt` value, redirect back to the home page, done.

But I see no way to add a global 401 handler? What I want to do is clear the JWT cookie and redirect to the login page. Doing it in the root `__error.svelte` seemed like the obvious place but if the error is triggered during SSR, then obviously I can't do anything with cookies, and `__error.svelte` isn't run a second time where `browser` is `true`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have a similar scenario where I need to capture 402 errors from external APIs and display an error page, but I'm struggling to understand how this is done.

Comment: Not yet, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can `throw` and then catch on the window object?

https://svelte.dev/repl/c6dddc73cbdd4f81883add43f5e3aa25?version=3.18.2

Comment: Tried your REPL but it didn't work right (as it looks from the comments like you already discovered). I wonder why changing a let var from the handler has no effect.

Comment: It is because by the time we catch the error, application is already in buenos noches state. As an alternative, you could probably employ a try/catch inside the components and emit events (EventTarget class), and then listen on the event to display an error to the user. Or.. try this `svelte-error-boundary` package, interesting approach. By the way, this has nothing to do with the 401 OP asked, but to answer your `why`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Use HTTP-only cookies for your token (optional, but could be better)

in `__layout.svelte`, we have

```
<script lang="ts" context="module">
  import { isPublic, isAuthenticated } from '$lib/auth/auth0_front';
  import type { Load } from '@sveltejs/kit';

  export const load: Load = async ({ page, session }) => {
    if (!isPublic(page.path) && !isAuthenticated(session)) {
      console.log('Unauthorized access to private page');
      return { redirect: '/', status: 302 };
    } else {
      console.log('Auth OK');
    }
    return {};
  };
</script>
```

And on front-end side we use a small wrapper around native fetch, that handle the 401 responses by redirecting the page to the homepage or login page.